# Suspicious "ChromeSync" pop-up in Android requesting credentials

Tags: malware, android, chrome

Since late May, I have been getting suspicious pop-up messages overlay on top of android Apps (see screenshots), requesting entering of the "ChromeSync Passphrase" for my google account.
[image]
[image]

I noticed that the pop-up will appear whenever the UI of any App resembles a login page, i.e. has text input fields and keywords such as "username" and "password". For example, the Reddit client App has an input field for the recipient's username on the messaging UI, thus will trigger the pop-up to appear.

I have tried disabling the Sync service on my mobile Chrome Browser, but the pop-up still occurs. I have also tried revoking the permissions for "Display over other apps" for all apps, but the pop-up still persists.

Is this normal behavior? Have my device been compromised?

Comment: I think ChromeSync passphrase will be prompted to enter **ONLY ONCE** when you set up Sync with Chrome on your device (eg If you reject that prompt and change your mind later, you will have to trigger the prompt by going to setting manually). Also, this popup only occur on Chrome app itself, so if it's anywhere else, it might be fake.

Comment: I think you should check the list of apps which have `draw on top` permission

Comment: @raspiduino. This is strange, I have never seen the prompt occurring on Chrome app itself, only on other apps. I don't see "draw on top" permission in "Special App Access" settings, only "Display over other apps" (which I think is the same, just under different names). Haven't noticed anything out of the ordinary. I have tried disabling this permission for all apps (including system apps), but that prompt still appears.

Comment: Hmm strange. You can try [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/127769/determine-which-app-is-drawing-on-top-of-other-apps) to find which app is drawing on top of your screen

Comment: Since this only appears on "login screen", it's possibly [the built-in Android autofill framework](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6197437?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid). While I've never seen the "ChromeSync" pop-up before, looks like it's because you previously [created your own custom passphrase for sync](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/165139#zippy=%2Ccreate-a-passphrase)

Answer (score 0):

A nuclear option to stop this popup is to delete Chrome's synced data and disable sync. Navigate to https://chrome.google.com/sync , be on the correct google account, click Clear Data and confirm.

---

I experienced this popup as well in various apps including "DROPOUT".

When I open Chrome on my phone, it asks me to enable sync, implying it's disabled.

According to https://chrome.google.com/sync I did have sync enabled in the past for bookmarks:

> Last time synced on December 6, 2016 at 3:33 PM

I clicked "Clear Data" on [this page](https://chrome.google.com/sync) and confirmed. The confirmation popup notes "This will stop sync".

I restarted my phone. I still saw the popup on my next login attempt. I closed the app without completing the login, tried again 5 minutes later and did not see the popup.

Answer (score 0):

The "ChromeSync passphrase" prompts seem to be coming from Google Play Services.

When you get the prompt, open your app switcher (press the bottom square button or use a gesture) and you'll see an entry for Google Play Services next to the entry for the app you were running (click the app's icon at the top of the screen to get info).

Google updates the Google Play Services app in the background on its own schedule, you have no control over it and I've never been able to find a change log for it.  There must have been a bug introduced in the May 2022 time frame that started causing this behavior.

I've been trying to find a solution for these prompts. I experience them mostly when clicking on things like a "change password" field in an app, and like you I was initially concerned because I don't ever sync or save passwords.